# Constant $a_{k}$ which normalizes integral is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$ define $$f_{k}(x) = a_{k}\cdot \left(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}\right)^{k}$$ where $a_{k}$'s are chosen such that $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f_{k}(x) \ dx =1 $$ Then show that $2a_{k} \leq \pi \cdot (k+1)$.

All I can see is that as $k \to \infty$, $f_{k}(x) \to 0$ for $x \neq 0$, but I am not sure how that helps in solving the problem. Also $$\left(\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}\right)^{k} = \sin^{2k}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) $$ but all this doesn't help me much. A good clean elaborate solution would do a world of good.

Answer (score 1):

As the integrand is positive $a_k$ is positive. As $1\ge2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$ in $[0,{\pi\over2}]$, 
$$
I_k=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^{2k}(0.5x)dx=4\int^{{\pi\over2}}_{0}\sin^{2k}(x)dx\ge8\int_0^{\pi\over2}\sin^{2k+1}(x)\cos(x)dx=8\int_0^1x^{2k+1}dx\\
\implies I_k\ge{4\over k+1}\implies {1\over2\pi}a_kI_k\ge{2a_k\over\pi( k+1)}\implies1\ge{2a_k\over\pi( k+1)}\\
\therefore 2a_k\le \pi(k+1)
$$